# einsum().eval Harmonic Mean

Tags: lambda, tensorflow, mean

I spent all night trying to form the equation for Harmonic
Mean using tensorflow.
There is nothing here that I need to use, it is a challenge to
myself. I am not giving up, just at a point that is beyond my
fumbling ability with mathmatics.
If you wonder what the Harmonic Mean is:
[Figuring the Harmonic Mean](http://www.statisticshowto.com/harmonic-mean/)

Can this work????
If so, where should I go from here???

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

i = tf.constant(0)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
c = lambda i: tf.constant(1)
d = lambda c: tf.mul(c, 3)
v1 = lambda b: tf.divide(1, b, name="v1")
v2 = lambda d: tf.divide(1, d, name='v2')

tf.mul(1000, tf.reciprocal(tf.einsum('i,i->1001', v1 * v2).eval()))
```

And, by the way I don't know very well how to use the website. Any criticism 
will be helpful/

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating the problem.

Given your set of samples `vals`, you can compute the harmonic mean with:

```
h = 1./tf.reduce_mean(1/vals)
```

For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf
vals = tf.constant([1,5,8,10.])
h = 1./tf.reduce_mean(1/vals)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(h))
```

Comment: I see. But it would be 4./tf.reduce_mean(1/vals). The formula is n/(sum(1/x(I)...1/x(n)) So for a large data set you would trapped entering values manually. I want to multiply the two vectors with a minimum of direct entry.

Comment: Or better yet count the entries, order the list, and enter a file of values. I think you might be on that path nessuno ... sorry to comment twice and edit too much.

Comment: A python question supplies a ground truth: len(a) / np.sum(1.0/a) 
 but we need unknowns and tensors.....

Comment: My formula is perfectly correct. n/(sum(1/x(I)...1/x(n)) = 1 / ( (sum(1/x(I)...1/x(n))/ n).
reduce_mean(1/vals) =  sum(1/x(I)...1/x(n))/ n. Thus 1 / reduce_mean(1/vals) = n/(sum(1/x(I)...1/x(n))

Comment: How do the vectors turn into constants?

Comment: of which constants are you talking about? n?

Comment: The point of figuring a harmonic mean is to predict harmony so that means that ratios of frequencies have to considered in vectors that have to be multiplied, so there really is no point to anything you have commented.

Comment: And by the way, n is not a constant in the first place. N is the is the position of x (a variable) in a sequence of many “x”’s. This is supposed to be a thread about tensorflow not barely using tensorflow like a calculator.

Comment: I did a little more reading and found out the Pythagoras had nothing to do with the system called “harmony.” Even though “harmony” is based on “Pythagorean Tuning.”Harmony is based on a 2/3 system of matching tones together. As the diminished fifth of D A flat is -11.73 or (2/3)^6 X 2^4...it turns out that the harmonic mean is useful using any set of numbers. I apologize for being short on this. And I am still interested in a music theory project.

Comment: Something like...given 12+1 keys any two keys can be described but a smaller set of the remaining (at this point) 12-2 keys will be “musical.” And I suggest 12-2 because at this point we can throw out the thirteenth key because we have defined our set and no longer need the thirteenth key and assume that repeating a tone is not useful. A certainty is that the frequency between any tone and its repetition higher or lower in the scale is a factor of 2.

Comment: The 13 X 11, 143 two note combination would each have a subset of 1 of 10 numbers. But this is only math.This is one array. A second array of the same size is possible, but fewer of the ultimate combinations would be musical. So there are, in the end two vectors created. The second as powerful as the first but more restricted. All with only 13 keys while a piano has eighty-eight keys. I am leaving for school this winter to study AI. Want to work with me Nessuno?